# Quill toolbar multiple Images select

Tags: quill

I am able to select only one image using the toolbar image select button . 
Using Image drop module I can able to drop many images at a time , but wondering Is there any way I can select multiple images  in single select using toolbar image select button  ( Using image handler ..? ) Thanks

[image]

Comment: I've got the same question. However I'm thinking of a workaround like integrating Quilljs with [Cloudinary's API](https://cloudinary.com) (includes drag/drop, multiple select, and you can offload large images to their server instead of in-house) to create a more user friendly interface..

Comment: Thanks for your comment . I am also looking at dropzone js and uploading them to Amazon s3 . I see Cloudinary is expensive .

Comment: have you find something? i am facing the same isssue

Comment: @SanskarTiwari - I am sorry I didn't find any option to do. :(

Comment: @Bujji i did actually you need to use image handler will post full answer in few hours

Comment: @SanskarTiwari Oh that is great and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was searching for answer on this, but found nothing straightforward, so consider my working solution with `addHandler` and `insertEmbed` methods from quill API doc. Read inline comments for more details. Also with this approach you can create upload image logic or any other middleware processing you want.

```js
//
// Init Quill
const quill = new Quill('#quill', {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      ['image']
    ]
  }
});

//
// Add handler for Image
const toolbar = quill.getModule('toolbar');
toolbar.addHandler('image', function() {
  //
  // Most of this code taken from
  // Quill library iself, from image
  // isertion part
  //
  const _this3 = this;
  let fileInput = this.container.querySelector('input.ql-image[type=file]');
  if (fileInput == null) {
    fileInput = document.createElement('input');
    fileInput.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    //
    // Adding line below with multiple
    // to allow selecting multiple images
    fileInput.setAttribute('multiple', 'multiple');
    //
    fileInput.setAttribute('accept', 'image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp, image/x-icon');
    fileInput.classList.add('ql-image');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
      if (fileInput.files != null && fileInput.files[0] != null) {
        //
        // Adding loop to process each
        // selected image
        for(let i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
            const range = _this3.quill.getSelection(true);
            //
            // After getting base64 we need
            // insertEmbed method to paste
            // our data as image.
            //
            // TIP: for those who was searching
            // the way to upload images instead of
            // inserting base64 - here at this point
            // you can achive this by your own logic
            // and pasting resulting link instead of
            // base64 (e.target.result)
            quill.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', e.target.result);
            //
            // After pasting image, put cursor
            // straight after insertion with
            // range.index + 1
            quill.setSelection(range.index + 1, 'image', Quill.sources.SILENT);
            fileInput.value = "";
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[i]);
        }
      }
    });
    this.container.appendChild(fileInput);
  }
  fileInput.click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="quill"></div>
```